# Поиск по первичному ключу типа INT быстрее, чем TEXT?

Tags: mysql

Решаю задачу получения строки из таблицы, соответствующей текущему запрошенному урлу.

На ум приходят два варианта (тут немаловажно с т.ч.зрения SEO-ЧПУ), чисто для примера:

1. Первый вариант:
   урл:

> site.ru/catalog/249-smartfon-samsung-galaxy-s20

Выдираем из урла 249 и находим запись в таблице по ключу типа INT:

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl1` (
        `id` INT(9) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        ...
        PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE,
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB;
    SELECT * FROM `tbl1` WHERE id=249;
```

2. Второй вариант (числовой id в урл отсутствует):

> site.ru/catalog/smartfon-samsung-galaxy-s20

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl2` (
    `id` TEXT NOT NULL,
    ...
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`(100)) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
SELECT * FROM `tbl2` WHERE id='smartfon-samsung-galaxy-s20';
```

- тут можно и первичным ключом сделать текстовое поле и вторичным.

Вопрос:
Намного ли быстрее будет поиск в первом варианте при прочих равных условиях, или примерно одинаково, если пренебречь размером индексов?

Comment: Делать текстовый идентификатор - так себе идея. У вас юзеры не смогут менять заголовок статьи. Также, вы какую нагрузку ожидаете, чтобы для вас разница между поиском по числу и по строке стала существенной?

Comment: *Намного ли быстрее будет поиск в первом варианте при прочих равных условиях* В пределе разница может составить более 10 крат. Реально - чем больше данных в кэше, тем меньше разница, но она в любом случае будет не в пользу строкового ПК.